# Why some email servers do not respond to smtlib.SMTP('xxxx')?

Tags: python, email

I tested the following code with different email servers and only smtp.gmail.com is responding to the following simple code:

```
>>> import smtplib
>>> s=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
>>> s.help()
'2.0.0  https://www.google.com/search?btnI&q=RFC+5321 b188sm4817528wmh.6    - gsmtp'
>>> s.quit()
(221, '2.0.0 closing connection b188sm4817528wmh.6 - gsmtp')
```

it is OK.

But this (and many other providers) time out:

```
>>> s=smtplib.SMTP('smtpmail.t-online.de')
```

returning error:

> error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

or

```
>>> s=smtplib.SMTP('wpxxxxxxxx.mailout.server-he.de',25)
```

returning:

> error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I thought because of SSL. So I used:

```
>>> smtplib.SMTP_SSL("wpxxxxxxx.mailout.server-he.de", 465)
```

tried with different port nr's. The email servers name sure correct. 
So what is unique about **smtp.gmail.com** ?
How could I make the others work?

-Thanks-

Comment: Try using port 587.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In trying this myself, I came across *possibly* a different problem, that may help others. Here are my findings.

Internet Service Providers are terrible. In every way.

In this instance, my ISP is blocking port 25.

From my local machine I tried this.

```
>>> import smtplib
>>> s=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
```

This eventually time out with the same `error: [Errno 10060]`.

Curious, I dropped back to telnet

```
$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
Trying ...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Huh? Why is GMail dropping my connection request? Unless...

```
$ ssh some.ec2.machine
$ python
>>> import smtplib
>>> s=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
>>>
```

It instantly connects.. Turns out, my ISP, who else but Comcast, is blocking all traffic on port 25.

By using a VPS, I was able to establish a connection to both Google mail, and other hosts.

I attempted the same telnet connection for your given address:

```
$ telnet smtpmail.t-online.de 25
telnet: connect to address 194.25.134.114: Connection refused
telnet: connect to address 194.25.134.115: Connection refused
```

In the case of a [`Connection Refused`](https://serverfault.com/a/725263/146878), this is misconfiguration on the server side.

Generally, a server will either accept the packet, or completely throw it away. In this situation, the server is running, and actively denying the connection.